# SQL windows authentication is not working after hosting locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, iis-7

Created a sample application with one aspx page and manager class. While running it from vs studio I'm getting output properly.
When I publish it and put those files inside interpub -> wwwroot -> New Folder and opened IIS manager, conver New Folder to Application and run it. Its failing, showing error that unable to connect to db and showing computer name.

I think after hosting application is trying to connect db using computer name rather than username. How to solve this? 
I'm adding my web.config file and manager class file below.

## web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestConnection" connectionString="data source=localhost\alex;initial catalog=Alex_Test; integrated security=SSPI; persist security info=False;  Trusted_Connection=Yes"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

## Manager.cs

```
string Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = null;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();        
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = null;   
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;
sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees ", conn);
dataSet = new DataSet();
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Employees");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either grant/give your IIS user for the worker access to the database or you can change your web.config connectionString to use explicit username and password.

```
Server=serverAddr;Database=dbName;User Id=Username;
Password=Password;
```

Comment: Thanks Landern.
Can you explain how to grant/give IIS user for the worker access to the database

Comment: MSDN has a link for that, your milage may vary depending on your setup and whether you're using MSSQL with SQL Management Studio. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172405(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I modified web.config of locally deployed code by adding below code.

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="userName" password="password" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and changed IIS authentication settings -> Anonymous Authentication to disable